# switch user menu, how is the list acquired?

Tags: unity

I am running Ubuntu version 16.04.2 desktop edition with Unity version 7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0, regularly upgraded.  This problem has also been seen in Ubuntu 14.04 that I previously ran (also regularly upgraded) that came pre-istalled on this System76 Kudu-Pro laptop (16.04 was a full re-install).  In the far upper right is a gear icon which gives a drop down menu that has choices like "About This Computer" and "Ubuntu Help...".  This menu also has "Lock/Switch Account..." (Ctrl+Alt+L) and a list of recently switched account usernames, including those from previous bootups.

The problem is that although this list is usually correct, there are times when it is *not* correct.  Most (about 75%, guessing) of the times I do a full system upgrade and reboot, it comes up wrong.  It also comes up wrong at other times, that I know of no particularly special activity.  What happens is that a few accounts I do not regularly use are put in the list and a few accounts that I do regularly use do not show up.  This is inconvenient because I switch accounts often (usually among a particular set big enough to use all of the menu maximum size of 12), so I need to get the missing accounts back into the list.  To do that I need to log out of an account to bring up the full user list to login to the missing ones.  All these accounts are set up as logging in without a password so that I can switch accounts quickly.  I use different accounts/userids for different purposes for better isolation such as each running its own copy of Firefox to isolate cookies, isolate different logins to the same web site, and work on different major projects.

I would like to find out why the code that makes the list of accounts in this menu gets them "wrong" sometimes.  Maybe it is intended to select them based on a different logic than I am expecting (recently logged in accounts).  If there is a way to hardcode what accounts will be listed, then I could hardcode the one I regularly use.

I would like to find out what code (what file) does this, where I may be able to determine what is causing the problem, and perhaps may be able to fix it or recode it to work with a hardcoded list.

Sorry that I do not know the name of this menu or the feature of caching (maybe recent) logins.

Comment: I *suspect* it involves `accountsservice` (likely via some kind of `dbus` call) - perhaps it is based on the timestamps of the files in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/`? My google-fu isn't strong enough to dig up any actual information though.

Comment: Using multiple accounts to run multiple copies of Firefox, and to "isolate" cookies/etc is memory and system resource wasteful. Learn how to use workspaces. Use user switching (profiles) in Firefox to "isolate" stuff. Don't have admin accounts without a password.